# Needleman Wunsch algorithm in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, bioinformatics

The [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) is an algorithm used in bioinformatics to align protein or nucleotide sequences.

Here is an implementation in Scala:

```
package vu.co.kaiyin.akkconcurrent

import vu.co.kaiyin.akkconcurrent.NeedlemanWunsch.{ResultEntry, Score, SimilarityFunc}

/**
  * Created by IDEA on 2/26/16.
  */
case class NeedlemanWunsch(private var s1: String, private var s2: String, gapPenalty: Int, sm: SimilarityFunc) {
  val borderDirection = (-9, -9)
  val verticalDirection = (-1, 0)
  val horizontalDirection = (0, -1)
  val matchDirection = (-1, -1)
  s1 = " " + s1
  s2 = " " + s2
  private val alignMat = new Array[Array[ResultEntry]](s1.length)
  private var alignResult: (String, String) = ("", "")

  // init alignment matrix
  def initAlignmentMatrix = {
    for (i <- (0 until s1.length)) {
      alignMat(i) = new Array[ResultEntry](s2.length)
      if (i == 0) {
        for (j <- 0 until s2.length) {
          alignMat(i)(j) = (j * gapPenalty, borderDirection)
        }
      } else {
        alignMat(i)(0) = (i * gapPenalty, borderDirection)
      }
    }
  }

  def fillAlignmentMatrix: Unit = {
    def getScore(i: Int, j: Int): Score = {
      if (alignMat(i)(j) != null) {
        alignMat(i)(j)._1
      } else {
        val tryMatch = getScore(i - 1, j - 1) + sm(s1(i), s2(j))
        val horizontalGap = getScore(i, j - 1) + gapPenalty
        val verticalGap = getScore(i - 1, j) + gapPenalty
        val m = Set(tryMatch, horizontalGap, verticalGap).max
        if (m == tryMatch) {
          alignMat(i)(j) = (m, matchDirection)
        } else if (m == horizontalGap) {
          alignMat(i)(j) = (m, horizontalDirection)
        } else {
          alignMat(i)(j) = (m, verticalDirection)
        }
        m
      }
    }
    for (i <- 1 until s1.length) {
      for (j <- 1 until s2.length) {
        val _ = getScore(i, j)
      }
    }
  }

  def align: NeedlemanWunsch = {
    initAlignmentMatrix
    fillAlignmentMatrix
    val alignBuffer1 = new StringBuffer()
    val alignBuffer2 = new StringBuffer()
    var rowNumber = s1.length - 1
    var colNumber = s2.length - 1
    var node = alignMat(rowNumber)(colNumber)
    while (node._2 != borderDirection) {
      val direction = node._2
      if(direction == matchDirection) {
        alignBuffer1.insert(0, s1(rowNumber))
        alignBuffer2.insert(0, s2(colNumber))
        rowNumber -= 1
        colNumber -= 1
      } else if(direction == verticalDirection) {
        alignBuffer1.insert(0, s1(rowNumber))
        alignBuffer2.insert(0, " ")
        rowNumber -= 1
      } else {
        alignBuffer1.insert(0, " ")
        alignBuffer2.insert(0, s2(colNumber))
        colNumber -= 1
      }
      node = alignMat(rowNumber)(colNumber)
    }
    alignResult = (alignBuffer1.toString, alignBuffer2.toString)
    this
  }

  override def toString = {
    s"\n${alignResult._1}\n${alignResult._2}\n"
  }
}

object NeedlemanWunsch {
  type Direction = (Int, Int)
  type Score = Int
  type ResultEntry = (Score, Direction)
  type SimilarityFunc = (Char, Char) => Int
}


object TestNeedlemanWunsch extends App {
  def sm(c1: Char, c2: Char) = if (c1 == c2) 1 else -1
  println(NeedlemanWunsch("GATTACA", "GCATGCU", -1, sm).align.toString)
}
```

Any suggestions for improvement are welcome.